# How to scroll up when expanding a section in magit-status?

Tags: magit

In the `magit-status` buffer, pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> shows or hides a given section, which is handy when looking at unstaged content and see what hunks can be staged.

However, when tabbing on a section, the buffer goes down, so the section I am trying to expand goes to the bottom of the buffer, thus hiding the expanded part of the section.  I then have to cycle using `recenter-top-bottom` to bring the section back to the top of the buffer.

Is there a way to automatically bring the section / entry to the top of the buffer when expanding it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Emacs v24.3.x, put his in your `.emacs`

```
(defadvice magit-toggle-section (after magit-section-hidden activate)
  (recenter-top-bottom 0))
```

If you're using Emacs v24.4.x, here is what I have come up with using an advice – although I am sure it is not perfect:

```
(defun magit-toggle-scroll-to-top () (recenter-top-bottom 0))
(advice-add 'magit-toggle-section :after #'magit-toggle-scroll-to-top)
```

Comment: The `advice-add` is void in Emacs v24.3.1, it is new advice facility introduced in Emacs v24.4

Comment: @CodyChan That's right: for older versions, `defadvice` should be used.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution for Emacs 24.4 worked perfectly for me. I've been going mad, thinking that any of the packages which I have is conflicting with Magit.

Answer (score 4):

On the `next` branch that's already supported. (Which shouldn't keep anybody from giving another answer here, explaining how to get the same effect with `master`).

Comment: I misread you question. A similar feature exists when moving between sections, but didn't in the case you actually asked about. But now I have implemented that for toggling sections too, and so this answer is correct now :-)

Comment: Awesome, I'll give the `next` branch a spin.

Comment: Not that be default it only does this for hunks, replace `magit-hunk-set-window-start` with `magit-section-set-window-start` in `magit-section-movement-hook` and `magit-section-show-hook` if you would like this behavior for all sections. Now that I think of it doing so for `magit-section-show-hook` would probably lead to problems.

Comment: Turns out this isn't as easy as I though and I had to revert this change for now.

Answer (score 0):

These work on the latest version of `magit` from Melpa (from **master** branch) as tested today.

While in the Magit Status window,

- `C-u j u` - Jump to the **u**nstaged section, expand it and bring that to the top of the buffer
- `C-u j s` - Jump to the **s**taged section, expand it and bring that to the top of the buffer

Similar action will apply to other `C-u j ..` bindings in the `magit-section-jump-map` too.

From [`magit.el` in **master** branch](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/40f33c9b8a0cd5ac39fdcca525dd734e7e79e1af/magit.el#L1710-L1720):

```el
(defvar magit-section-jump-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "z") 'magit-jump-to-stashes)
    (define-key map (kbd "n") 'magit-jump-to-untracked)
    (define-key map (kbd "u") 'magit-jump-to-unstaged)
    (define-key map (kbd "s") 'magit-jump-to-staged)
    (define-key map (kbd "f") 'magit-jump-to-unpulled)
    (define-key map (kbd "p") 'magit-jump-to-unpushed)
    (define-key map (kbd "r") 'magit-jump-to-pending)
    map)
  "Submap for jumping to sections in `magit-status-mode'.")
```

#### Answer

To answer your specific application to review the hunks in unstaged section, do `C-u j u` in the Magit Status buffer.

*Applies to the magit master branch code; haven't tried out the next branch.*

#### An example workflow using these bindings

1. `M-x magit-status`
2. Stage the files you want using `s`
3. Expand the staged files showing the hunk diffs, while also positioning the top of the staged section to the top of the buffer: `C-u j s`
4. Commit `c c`, opens COMMIT buffer [in a split window](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/913c74477796a10dd01bb225e88fa423c312ad34/setup-files/setup-magit.el#L22-L30)
5. Write log while reviewing staged diffs in other window. If diff exceeds the window height, I use the ['scroll other window commands'](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/913c74477796a10dd01bb225e88fa423c312ad34/setup-files/setup-windows-buffers.el#L308-L316).
6. Finish commit `C-c C-c`.

Comment: Although these are indeed useful shortcuts, this is not exactly what I was after: I want the current file, or hunk, or section to scroll to the top when I expand it so I can see most of the diff in that current change.